# Number of ways to put $n$ red cards and $k$ black cards into $4$ distinct jars so that every jar has a card.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

So if we define two functions $f_1 [n]\rightarrow [4]$ and $f_2[k]\rightarrow [4]$, in order to do this problem we need for the functions to be onto.  This is simple enough, right?  If $f_1$ is onto then there are $\binom{n-3}{3}$ possible functions.  If $f_2$ is onto then there are $\binom{k-3}{3}$ functions.  It follows that $\binom{k-3}{3}\binom{n-3}{3}$ gives the number of ways to put one red card AND one black card into each of the jars.  This under counts what I want.  Taking it one step further we see  $\binom{k-3}{3}\binom{n-3}{3}+\binom{k-3}{3}+\binom{n-3}{3}$ is the number of ways to put 1 black card AND 1 red card into a jar, 1 black card into each jar or 1 red card into each jar.

...This is where I get stuck.  I know that this still under counts what I want.  I need to include the cases where the cards mix.  For instance, jar 1 has a red and black, jar 2 has a black, jar 3 has a red and jar 4 has a red.  Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Why does the color matter? It's just putting $n+k$ cards into 4 jars so that every jar has one card?

Comment: @angryavian are you sure color doesn't matter?  Wouldn't if we let $n=5$ and $k=4$, then the number of ways to put one red card and one black card, together, into each jar be like 1960.  But $\binom{9+3}{3}=220$.

Comment: @angryavian pretzelman wishes to count distinct arrangements of indistinguishable cards of two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\binom{x+y-1}{y-1}$ is the ways to distribute $x$ indistinguishable object into $y$ distinct containers.   NB: this count does *not* guarantee a minimum of one object per container.   It's essentially counting distinct ways of arranging $y-1$ dividers and $x$ objects in a line.

There are $\binom{n+3}{3}\binom{k+3}{3}$ ways to put n-red and k-black cards into four jars.

There are $\binom{4}{3}\binom{n+2}{2}\binom{k+2}{2}$ ways to pick three jars and put the cards into them, as above.

There are $\binom{4}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}\binom{k+1}{1}$ ways to pick two jars and put the cards into them, as above.

There is but $4$ ways to pick one jar and put the cards into them as above.

Then use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion

$$\binom{n+3}{3}\binom{k+3}{3}
-\binom{4}{3}\binom{n+2}{2}\binom{k+2}{2}
+\binom{4}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}\binom{k+1}{1}
-4$$

Comment: I sort of messed up phrasing my solution.  I mean to put minus signs instead of plus signs.  I see what you're saying.  So you simply counted the number of all functions and are cleaving off each of the values that breach the onto condition.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, we are finding the number of solutions to the following system:

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$
$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=k$
where $x_i+y_i\geq1$ for $i=1,2,3,4$

What we do is first count the total non negative solutions without restrictions and then minus out solutions that do not follow the restrictions.

Total solutionss = ${n+3\choose3}\cdot{k+3\choose 3}$

One restriction violated (assuming exactly one pair of $x_i,y_i$ are both $0$) = ${4\choose1}\cdot{n+3\choose2}\cdot{k+3\choose2}$

Two restriction violated (assuming exactly two pairs of $x_i,y_i$ are both $0$) = ${4\choose2}\cdot{n+3\choose1}\cdot{k+3\choose1}$

Three restriction violated (assuming exactly three pairs of $x_i,y_i$ are both $0$) = ${4\choose3}\cdot{n+3\choose0}\cdot{k+3\choose0}$

Four restriction violated (assuming exactly four pairs of $x_i,y_i$ are both $0$) = $0$